# Repo and its clone disagree about HEAD pointer

Tags: git, git-branch, git-clone, git-remote

I’m trying to rename my master branch to 'liveBranch', create a new branch ('devBranch'), then clone the repo (call it repo A) in another folder on the same computer (call it repo B). But when I do so, if I do a `git branch -a` on repo B, it shows the HEAD of repo A to be pointing to 'devBranch' while `git branch -a` on repo A claims that 'liveBranch' is checked out.

Here are my exact steps (note: repoA is a non-empty directory):

```
cd path/to/repoA
git init
git add .
git commit
git branch -m master liveBranch
git branch devBranch
git clone path/to/repoA path/to/repoB 
cd path/to/repoB
```

Running `git branch -a` in repo B returns:

```
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/liveBranch
```

While running `git branch -a` in repo A returns:

```
  devBranch
* liveBranch
```

I thought this might be because both the two branches are actually pointing to the same commit, so neither repo is technically wrong. So I made a commit on one of the branches in repo A to advance the branch and did a `git pull` in repo B, but the disconnect is still occurring (repo B and repo A disagree on what branch repo A has checked out).

Comment: I tried your example and `git branch -a` in repo B says liveBranch is checked out. git version 2.8.2

Comment: I'm running git version 1.7.10. torek's answer reproduced my problem with 2.8.1, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something a bit wrong with your "exact steps", because if I begin by trying to reproduce the problem:

> ```
> cd path/to/repoA
> git init
> git add .
> git commit
> ```

I get this on my system:

```
$ cd /tmp; mkdir btest; cd btest
$ mkdir repoA; cd repoA
$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/btest/repoA/.git/
$ git add .
$ git commit
On branch master

Initial commit

nothing to commit
$
```

It seems as though perhaps you are doing your `git init` in a repository that already exists and has some commit(s), otherwise `master` would still be an unborn branch at this point.  Anyway, so now I change your steps a bit:

```
$ echo 'dummy repo for testing' > README
$ git add .
$ git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 82f36fb] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git branch -m master liveBranch
$ git branch devBranch
$ git branch
  devBranch
* liveBranch
$
```

Now let's try cloning this to /tmp/btest/repoB:

```
$ git clone /tmp/btest/repoA /tmp/btest/repoB
Cloning into '/tmp/btest/repoB'...
done.
$ cd ../repoB
$ git status
On branch liveBranch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/liveBranch'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
$
```

and it is working the way you would like.

Let's take a different approach to repeating the problem, beginning with removing both test repositories, then making a fresh repository with `HEAD` pointing to devBranch, then cloning that repository:

```
$ cd /tmp/btest
$ rm -rf *
$ mkdir repoA; cd repoA; git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /tmp/btest/repoA/.git/
$ echo > README; git add README; git commit -m initial
[master (root-commit) 8278cc4] initial
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+)
 create mode 100644 README
$ git branch -m master devBranch
$ cd ..; git clone repoA repoB; (cd repoB; git status; git branch -A)
Cloning into 'repoB'...
done.
On branch devBranch
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/devBranch'.
nothing to commit, working directory clean
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
$
```

So we have repoB in a suitable state.  Now we alter repoA so that it has `HEAD` pointing to `liveBranch`:

```
$ (cd repoA; git checkout -b liveBranch; git branch)
Switched to a new branch 'liveBranch'
  devBranch
* liveBranch
$
```

If we ask git to `git pull` in repoB, what should we now *expect* to happen?  Well, let's see what *does* happen (note, this is with Git version 2.8.1; pre-1.8.4 behavior would be a bit different in some cases):

```
$ cd repoB; git pull
From /tmp/btest/repoA
 * [new branch]      liveBranch -> origin/liveBranch
Already up-to-date.
$ git branch -a
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/liveBranch
$
```

Now let's try something different, namely, running `git fetch` in repoB, and also `git ls-remote`:

```
$ git fetch
$ git branch -a
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/liveBranch
$ git ls-remote
From /tmp/btest/repoA
8278cc44d45cad50f34dc2c788cd9df7bf9375ec    HEAD
8278cc44d45cad50f34dc2c788cd9df7bf9375ec    refs/heads/devBranch
8278cc44d45cad50f34dc2c788cd9df7bf9375ec    refs/heads/liveBranch
```

Clearly neither `git pull` nor `git fetch` is reading the new remote `HEAD` state, or if it is, is falling back to name-to-ID translation.  Let's update repoA with a new commit and re-fetch:

```
$ (cd ../repoA; git commit -m update --allow-empty)
[liveBranch 2234cf1] update
$ git fetch
remote: Counting objects: 1, done.
remote: Total 1 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (1/1), done.
From /tmp/btest/repoA
   8278cc4..2234cf1  liveBranch -> origin/liveBranch
$ git branch -a
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/liveBranch
$ git ls-remote
From /tmp/btest/repoA
2234cf14c9f7c63785e8fe31b7e5f37bcaf51823    HEAD
8278cc44d45cad50f34dc2c788cd9df7bf9375ec    refs/heads/devBranch
2234cf14c9f7c63785e8fe31b7e5f37bcaf51823    refs/heads/liveBranch
$
```

So, yes, Git simply fails to update `remotes/origin/HEAD` after the initial clone, at least when using absolute paths.  Changing the URL to `file:///tmp/btest/repoA` makes no difference:

```
$ git config remote.origin.url file:///tmp/btest/repoA
$ git fetch
$ git branch -a
* devBranch
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/devBranch
  remotes/origin/liveBranch
```

and a quick look at the source code suggest that after the initial `clone` step, git never bothers to update `remotes/origin/HEAD`.

Comment: Fantastic exploration, thank you very much torek. Your assumption at the start of your answer was correct: I forgot to make a note that repoA was an existing, non-empty directory (now edited with a note).

Answer (score 0):

> It seems as though perhaps you are doing your `git init` in a repository that already exists and has some commit(s), otherwise `master` would still be an unborn branch at this point.

Even if master is unborned, you still can (now, Git 2.30, Q1 2021) rename it:

This is part of the users training, to prepare them for future change of `init.defaultBranch` configuration variable.

See [commit 675704c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/675704c74dd4476f455bfa91e72eb9e163317c10), [commit cc0f13c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cc0f13c57dedaf62c9f852b6bf363aee7e3392f1), [commit cfaff3a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34), [commit 1296cbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1296cbe4b4675f429eb20b85bb86ec61546103fb) (11 Dec 2020) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 772bdcd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/772bdcd4296b259d52aafb0badd79872e9db3bb3), 18 Dec 2020)</sup>

> ### [`branch -m`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34): allow renaming a yet-unborn branch
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Johannes Schindelin</sup>

> In one of the next commits, we would like to give users some advice regarding the initial branch name, and how to modify it.
>
> To that end, it would be good if [`git branch -m <name>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/cfaff3aac8063ec72f03c6761328c7fa44a15b34/Documentation/git-branch.txt#L125)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-branch#Documentation/git-branch.txt--m))</sup> worked in a freshly initialized repository without any commits.
> Let's make it so.

The test shows that in action:

```sh
test_expect_success 'branch -m with the initial branch' '
    git init rename-initial &&
    git -C rename-initial branch -m renamed &&
    test renamed = $(git -C rename-initial symbolic-ref --short HEAD) &&
    git -C rename-initial branch -m renamed again &&
    test again = $(git -C rename-initial symbolic-ref --short HEAD)
```